# The "question down (¿)" symbol does not display correctly when compiling with xetex

Tags: xetex, spanish

When you compile all the "¿" they appear as "£". I can use "?`" or "\textquestiondown", the problem comes when I have to use verbatim environments where it is not possible to use those.

I only have the packages:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: It works! thank you, I had no idea that XeTeX did not need foontenc.